# assign permission set to profile?

Tags: profile, user, permission-sets, user-management, user-profile

We normally add permission sets to each user individually, however, a certain profile in our company always requires a specific permission set

Question:
Permission sets can be assigned to Users, but can they be assigned to Profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are not able to assign Permission set to Profile. We can assign it to the User only.